# PHP header returning with spaces when using variables?

Tags: php, variables, header, spacing

I have asked a question earlier but I think I missed the point so I'm gonna post it again.

I'm using the header Content-Disposition.

The code I used to do so was like this:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='{$name}'");
```

It returns this:

> Content-Disposition   attachment; filename=' Bassnectar - Bass Head Official.mp3 '

Note the spaces before and after the quotes. This is a problem because it changes the extension from ".mp3" to ".mp3 " which is recognized as a different file. There has to be some way to fix this. I've changed everything, I've googled everything. I don't know what is left to do?

Comment: Have you tried using trim() on $name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should url encode and trim extra whitespace before placing in the header.

```
$name = rawurlencode(trim($name));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='{$name}'");
```

**Final Solution**

```
$name = $extract['original_name'];
$name2 = urlencode(trim($name));
$name3 = str_replace("+", " ", $name2);
$quote = '"';
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$quote{$name3}$quote");
```

I am pretty sure you could clean this up:

```
$name = $extract['original_name'];
$name = urlencode(trim($name));
$name = str_replace("+", " ", $name);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$name}\"");
```

And, if the urlencode does not seem to make a difference, I am pretty certain you can just do this:

```
$name = $extract['original_name'];
$name = trim($name);

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$name}\"");
```

Comment: I tried it that way and it returned a file named "{urlencode(trim(" without the quotes.

Comment: @RosengustaGarrett Sorry about that, wasn't thinking!  I fixed the answer.  Please try it and let me know if it solved the problem.

Comment: That worked really good. It gave me Content-Disposition attachment; filename=Bassnectar+-+Bass+Head+Official.mp3 SO if I use str_replace("+", " ", $name) It should hopefully work. *cross fingers*

Comment: @RosengustaGarrett Hold up! The browser **should** automatically decode that correctly therefore accessing the correct file.  If it does not work, then remove the `urlencode()` call and leave just `trim()`

Comment: @RosengustaGarrett Good song, btw!

Comment: So when I used `str_replace("+", " ", $name)` it gave me `Content-Disposition attachment; filename=Bassnectar - Bass Head Official.mp3` and it trys to save a file named `Bassnectar` so I added quotes single quotes around `{$name3}` and it saved a file named `'Bassnectar`. I then remembered you need to use double quotes so I made this: `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="{$name3}"');` but it saved a file called `{$name3}`

Comment: @RosengustaGarrett You should not have to do the str_replace.

Comment: @RosengustaGarrett Updated the answer, please try `rawurlencode` instead of `urlencode`

Comment: I'll try it your new way and see if it shortens up my code a bit but if not either way it works :D

Comment: the rawurlencode() gave me hex code. So I think I'll leave it where it is and try not to push my luck. Thanks so much though!

Comment: I'm new here and got 14 rep. I need 1 more rep to upvote. I did Checkmark your answer though:D

Comment: @RosengustaGarrett Looks like you have enough now.

Comment: @RosengustaGarrett Welcome to the site!

Comment: @RosengustaGarrett For future reference, I added a few notes to the answer.  Also, I meant upvote the answer... Comment votes don't count for points, :P

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
<?php
$str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str);
?>
```

or

```
<?php
$string = trim(ereg_replace(' +', ' ', $string));
?>
```

or

```
<?php
$name=preg_replace('/\s+/','',$name);
?>
```

This last one works probably the best for you.

Those will remove the spaces from your string, just make sure there's a corresponding file to match,

Comment: $name=preg_replace('/\s+/','',$name);


Returned: Bassnectar-BassHeadOfficial.mp3 (I used a song as a test) That works good except it removed every space in the title. I could do the name thing str_replace(" ", "", $name)


$string = trim(ereg_replace(' +', ' ', $string));


Returned: Bassnectar


$str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str);


Returned: Bassnectar

Comment: Why remove _all_ whitespaces? The problem was only the space at the beginning, I think.

Comment: @RosengustaGarrett - You only want the space removed from the extension... Can you make two variables called $name and $ext then use the space-remover for the $ext and merge it with $name like '$name' . '$ext'

Comment: @Tadeck I'm not trying to remove all white spaces just the space from the very front and very back.

Comment: @mesh I'll need to extract the extension first so I'll do that and see how it goes. I'll write back if it works.

Comment: @RosengustaGarrett - Very glad to hear.

Comment: @RosengustaGarrett: That is what I said. I responded to mesh's answer, not your comment (which appeared aprox. 1 minute before mine) :)